# join multiple tables with multiple 'and'

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

I have 3 tables which I would like to combine.  One is a list of Personnel, one is a list of Schedules for each person in the Personnel table, and the third is a list of temporary schedules for each person.  I would like to return a table that contains some information from personnel and then their schedules and temp schedules where the two type of schedules begin and ends date meet certain criteria.  I tried the following SQL code...

```
SELECT Personnel.ID, Personnel.Name, Schedules.LinkID, Schedules.BeginDate, Schedules.EndDate, Schedules.Shift, tempSchedules.LinkID, tempSchedules.BeginDate, tempSchedules.EndDate, tempSchedules.Shift
FROM ((Personnel INNER JOIN Schedules ON (Schedules.LinkID = Personnel.ID  
AND ((Schedules.BeginDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (Schedules.EndDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (Schedules.BeginDate <=#01-June-2014# AND Schedules.EndDate >=#30-June-2014#))))
INNER JOIN tempSchedules ON (tempSchedules.LinkID = Personnel.ID
AND ((TempSchedules.BeginDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (TempSchedules.EndDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (TempSchedules.BeginDate <=#01-June-2014# AND TempSchedules.EndDate >=#30-June-2014#))))
ORDER BY Schedules.Shift
```

which works, except it returns results where only both TempSchedules and Schedules begin and end dates meet the criteria and joins the columns of TempSchedules along side of Schedules columns. For example, I get the following columns...

```
ID | Name | Schedules.LinkID | Schedules.BeginDate | Schedules.EndDate | Schedules.Shift | TempSchedules.LinkID | TempSchedules.BeginDate | TempSchedules.EndDate | TempSchedules.Shift
```

I would like it to look like this...

```
ID | Name | LinkID | BeginDate | EndDate | Shift
```

So I would get the columns from Schedule that match the date criteria, and then get columns from TempSchedules that meet the date criteria.

```
ID | Name | LinkID | BeginDate     | EndDate     | Shift

01 | Bob  | 52     | 01-April-2014 | 01-Dec-2014 | Days
02 | Tim  | 34     | 01-Jan-2014   | 01-Aug-2014 | Days
03 | Bob  | 52     | 01-Jun-2014   | 15-Jun-2014 | Swings    //this is from temp schedules)
04 | Tim  | 34     | 07-Jun-2014   | 28-Jun-2014 | Graves   //this is from temp schedules)
```

I am using Javascript to access an Microsoft Access Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using UNION ALL: something like this:

```
SELECT  ID, Name, LinkID, BeginDate, EndDate, Shift
FROM (
SELECT Personnel.ID, Personnel.Name, Schedules.LinkID, Schedules.BeginDate, Schedules.EndDate, Schedules.Shift
FROM Personnel INNER JOIN Schedules ON (Schedules.LinkID = Personnel.ID  
AND ((Schedules.BeginDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (Schedules.EndDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (Schedules.BeginDate <=#01-June-2014# AND Schedules.EndDate >=#30-June-2014#)))
union all
SELECT Personnel.ID, Personnel.Name,tempSchedules.LinkID, tempSchedules.BeginDate, tempSchedules.EndDate, tempSchedules.Shift
FROM Personnel INNER JOIN tempSchedules  ON (tempSchedules.LinkID = Personnel.ID  
AND ((tempSchedules.BeginDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (tempSchedules.EndDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (tempSchedules.BeginDate <=#01-June-2014# AND tempSchedules.EndDate >=#30-June-2014#)))
)
ORDER BY Shift
```

Comment: I've tried this SQL statement straight in MS Access and I get "Syntax Error in FROM Clause" error.  I've played around with the parenthesis a bit, but still get an error.  

Usually Access highlights where in the statement it is having a problem, but in this case it just puts the cursor at the end of the statement.

Comment: I've just updated it: try now: I've tried it in an Access database and it works, it should for you too.